# C# ASP.NET Go to previous page and retain session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.Net/C# web project and I have this Home page where I search Student's info in a tabular form. The Student Number column is hyperlink. When the users click on the number, they will be redirected to another page where they can update info.

My concern now is everytime the value changes, the page reloads and that's good because the value is refreshed. But when I want to go back to home page thru brower's back button, it still remains on the same page since it has been reloaded. So I need to click back again and again if I made lots of changes.

So I added a button which redirects to the Home Page.

```
Response.Redirect("~/SharesHaircut.aspx");
```

But the session is being reset. 
I want to retain the search result on the home page when I go back. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you give some code, are you resetting session values

Comment: Post some code , where are you using your session ?